# turn "|" separated values into list in r

Tags: r, list, format

I have a table with values seperated by a "|" and a space on both sides.

I am trying to make a list so that the values from all rows will appear one after another.

Current:

```
company name    codes
a   324191
b   324122
c   324110 | 325110
d   3119  | 311520 | 31141 | 311920 | 311520  | 312111 | 311351 | 311999 | 324191
f   326150
```

Desired:

```
324191
324122
324110
325110
3119
311520
31141
311920
311520
312111
311351
311299
324191
326150
```

Comment: try `unlist(strsplit(df$codes, split = " | ", fixed = T))`

Comment: Also `trimws(scan(what = character(), text = df$codes, sep = "|"))
`.